# How to receive error while inserting in store?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, indexeddb

I am using [angular-indexedDB](https://github.com/bramski/angular-indexedDB) for indexedDB in AngularJS.
I want to receive error if insert is not successful. But I am not getting any error it just comes out of the function if I run the same code twice as I have made name unique.

**Error**:

> ConstraintError  return _this.store.add(item);
>
> ConstraintError req =
>   this.store.openCursor();

**Code**:

```
angular.module('myModuleName')
  .controller('myControllerName', function($scope, $indexedDB) {

    $scope.objects = [];

    $indexedDB.openStore('people', function(store){

      store.insert({"ssn": "444-444-222-111","name": "John Doe", "age": 57}).then(function(e){console.log('inside insert');});

      store.getAll().then(function(people) {  
        // Update scope
        $scope.objects = people;
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think adding error callback inside promise `.then` should work

Also do create a getAll method to retrieve all data from `objects`, in that do `response.data` to get data returned from server.

**Code**

```
angular.module('myModuleName')
  .controller('myControllerName', function($scope, $indexedDB) {

    $scope.objects = [];

    $scope.getAll = function(){
       store.getAll().then(function(response) {  
          // Update scope
          $scope.objects = response.data;
       });
    };
    $indexedDB.openStore('people', function(store){

       store.insert({"ssn": "444-444-222-111","name": "John Doe", "age": 57})
       .then(function(e){
           console.log('inside insert');
           //reload data only call get succeed
           $scope.getAll();
        }, function(error){
           //do error handling stuff here
           //you will get error returned from server here.
           console.log('Error here', error)
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You Pankaj, now I am able to detect the error but still it comes out of the function.

 Error here =  A mutation operation in the transaction failed because a constraint was not satisfied. For example, an object such as an object store or index already exists and a new one was being attempted to be created.

ConstraintError
 

return _this.store.add(item);

ConstraintError
req = this.store.openCursor();

Comment: @dilpeshjain didn't you handled that error on server side?

Comment: My aim is to find out whether this entry is already in the DB or not, on the basis of result I want to perform some tasks.

Comment: @dilpeshjain so isn't it correct that database is returning constraint validation? I'd say that..before calling an insert method, do create a new `method` on server side pass & pass this object to it and check that already exist or not.. if it exists then return an error an show that on client end..otherwise proceed with insert..

Comment: Its correct but why it is coming out of the function, I have some other tasks to perform in the same function. The reason behind using angular and indexed is to perform most of the tasks in client side.

Comment: @dilpeshjain see getting an exception will alway stop code execution and gets out of that loop unless you have `try catch finally` block implementation.. I"d say that do look at that syntax..do your work inside `finally` block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107409/discussion-between-dilpesh-jain-and-pankaj-parkar).